# Можно ли установить 2 разные ОЗУ?

Tags: железо

Здравствуйте!

В связи с неисправностью с 1-ой платки, нужно её заменить.Можно ли установить на 1 компьютер (3 шткуи)[OCZ OCZ3G1333LV6GK](http://market.yandex.ru/model.xml?modelid=3732725&hid=191211) и (2 штуки)[OCZ3G1333LV2G](http://market.yandex.ru/model.xml?modelid=6219827&hid=191211&show-uid=915891513641162781).

Спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Совместно можно использовать любые совместимые с материнкой плашки памяти, вне зависимости от марки, объема и частоты. но если использовать плашки с разной частотой, то вся память будет работать с частотой той плашки, у которой максимальная частота меньше. То есть если использовать совместно 3 плашки на `1333Mhz` и одну на `800Mhz`, то вся память будет работать с частотой `800Mhz`.

Comment: @autonomous, благодарю, эти планки имеют одинаковые хар-ки вроде бы. Спасибо за подробное объяснение..

Answer (score 2):

Может мне кажется, но они абсолютно одинаковы по характеристикам. Конечно можно.

Comment: @ArcherGodson, мне тоже так кажется. Только встаёт вопрос - почему, у них название разные, и одна есть в продаже, а другой нет!?

Comment: @ArcherGodson, На разных сайтах хар-ки разные. Я, по правде сказать, в замутнение - кому верить..

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, по маркеровке лучше свериться с сайтом производителя.

Comment: @ArcherGodson, Видимо я плохо искал, но на сайте производителя, по моему ничего нет.